# Prevent execution of js code on click from other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-button-prototype', function(){
            if ($(this).closest('.collectionContainer').find('input[type="text"]').val() == '') {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Example 1 catch click event for all new added element with given class, but not prevent execution of the code.

```
    $('.add-button-prototype').click(function(e){
        if ($(this).closest('.collectionContainer').find('input[type="text"]').val() == '') {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Second example work only for loaded element with given class and not for new added after init of page. But it prevent execution of the code.

How to catch all element of same class, old and newly added and prevent execution of code if condition are true;

Comment: How you add the button $('.add-button-prototype'), can you show the html and the code when you are adding the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `return false` add `e.preventDefault();`

So your code should look like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-button-prototype', function(e){
        if ($(this).closest('.collectionContainer').find('input[type="text"]').val() == '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe this is not the problem anymore and it's related to something else. Can you reproduce the bug on a jsfiddle snippet?